# How could Earth's geography be altered by multiple asteroids? Evacuated and later repopulated

Tags: science-fiction, terraforming, far-future

I am curious if anyone has feedback about a scenario in which, say 500 years or so in the future (assuming AI and biotechnology and interstellar travel are all advanced), a series of asteroids is heading for earth. Perhaps 5-10 of varying sizes that hit Earth spaced out over 100-200 years. **How big would some of them have to be to totally smash apart some continents into islands and different shapes**? The goal is to have the landmass geography significantly altered without totally destroying earth or changing its tilt significantly.

I am aware that the impacts will cause volcanic winters and probably wipe out all or most of the life on earth. **Is it possible that any life or vegetation would survive?**

**How long would humanity/machines have to wait to come back and terraform and repopulate certain parts of earth with life?**

**How long would this process possibly take and what shape would you expect the Earth and landmasses to be in after say, 500-1000 years after the last asteroid impact when we came back to see it all? (What would the land look like in parts of planet near impact site vs. parts of the planet that weren't near any impact sites?)**

**Would the atmosphere and oceans be ok for life after 500-1000 years?**

Comment: There are MANY questions embedded in this one post. That makes it very hard to give a comprehensive answer. In the future, please limit to one actual question per post and do not be afraid to make multiple posts. You can even have the successive posts reference each other. Experience shows you'll get much better answers if you follow this practice.

Comment: Welcome to the site, P. Payton. While I have tried to write detailed answers for all your questions as a welcome gesture, SRM is right in pointing out that you have filled your post will a bit too many questions. You may want to post just one fundamental question (e.g. _How many and what sized asteroids need to collide with Earth in order to fragment continents into islands?_) and then post another question for the next query. This way, it would be much easier for fellow members to focus at just one thing and write a well researched, detailed answer for you. Nice scenario btw. Interesting :)

Comment: thank you SRM and Youstay. I will take that advice in the future and perhaps repost these questions later separately

Comment: Have you read _[Seveneves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seveneves)_? It's a big part of the plot.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, what Alexander has already mentioned.

An *asteroid* large enough to smash continents into islands would either have to hit Earth at very high velocity, or be about 1/4th the diameter of the moon. In case of former, a KT-extinction-sized asteroid (~10 km diameter) would have to collide with Earth head-on, as in, it ought to be travelling in the opposite direction of Earth's orbit around the sun. Considering that Earth is orbiting the sun at about 29 km/s, the relative velocity of the asteroid at the time of impact would be about 50-60 km/s. Even then, it will tear a gaping hole in the continent it crashes into, instead of immediately fragmenting it into islands. However, the force of the impact would send unimaginably powerful seismic waves (I am assuming richter scale 11.4 or so) all over Earth's crust, forming fault lines on almost all continents. These fault lines *might* later continue to expand, based on how much the impact changes the tectonic activity underground.

In case of a quarter-moon-sized asteroid, the destruction is difficult to estimate. Not only will it send extreme seismic waves and fracture the crust near the place it lands, in fact part of Earth's crust will be blown out into space and some fragments might end up landing on Venus or Mars. It will also have an extremely detrimental effect on the atmosphere and oceans. Detailed effects are difficult to predict, but you can be certain that all of complex life will go extinct and probably only unicellular life and some worms would survive.

**Is it possible that any life or vegetation would survive?**

Maybe. Difficult to say. Virus and unicellular organisms would definitely survive. The scale of extinction would far exceed end Permian extinction levels. Some seeds will probably be lucky enough to survive in a cave or tunnel and would later sprout (after 200 years or so) to start vegetation again.

**How long would humanity/machines have to wait to come back and terraform and repopulate certain parts of earth with life?**

This really depends on the technology level at that time. A very advanced race could return just after 10-20 years and begin with removing the soot and ash hung in the atmosphere, in order to end the long permanent winter and ice age.

Humans of modern technology level will not be able to return before 200 years or so, when the dust and ash has finally settled and atmosphere is getting to become breathable again. That is to say, if the impact does not initiate multiple long term instances of volcanism.

**How long would this process possibly take and what shape would you expect the Earth and landmasses to be in after say, 500-1000 years after the last asteroid impact when we came back to see it all? (What would the land look like in parts of planet near impact site vs. parts of the planet that weren't near any impact sites?)**

Impossible to say, considering we don't know what technology level and resources those people will have. The main issue after the impacts is how long it takes for the dust and ash to settle down, ending the ice age. Another issue (in case of a mega asteroid) is the possible permanent damage to the atmospheric composition, due to extensive volcanic activity and the alteration of carbon, water, oxygen and nitrogen cycles.

In case we get lucky and Earth suffers no permanent damage, the ecosystems would be beginning to form. Most of the planet would be covered only in grasses, with a few shrubs and occasionally a tree here and there. All large sized animals (anything larger than a cat) would be gone forever. A few bird species might have survived, now beginning to repopulate. Oceans would have mostly recovered by now, albeit the loss of all large sized vertebrate species (anything fish or mammal, larger than 5-6 feet).

In case we did not get lucky, Earth would be ravaged by extreme storms. Volcanic activity would be peaking and the atmosphere would be too dusty and corrosive (due to high levels of CO$_2$ and SO$_2$) to breathe. Seasons would have been irreparably damaged due to alteration in the axial tilt (it might have increased or decreased than 23° or its angle changed. probably increased). All landmasses would be covered in permafrost and the oceans would also have formed a layer of ice, as it would have been millenia upon millenia since Earth fell into ice age. The largest creatures you would expect to see anywhere, would be earthworms, living deep inside the soil. These too, would be sparse and their populations dwindling.

Excluding the impact site, most landmasses would have survived intact. However, gaping craters would have formed over the fault lines. In general, the geography would have survived, but topography of all continents would have been changed so intensely, that no region would be recognizable at all by its features.

**Would the atmosphere and oceans be ok for life after 500-1000 years?**

Read above.

Answer (score 3):

In order to smash whole continents apart, impact must be big. Chicxulub asteroid, the one that killed dinosaurs, was about 10 km in size, and although it left a crater almost 200 km in diameter, this did not change the shape of continents very much. I think we need an asteroid about 10 times more massive to cause break up of continental plates and massive lava eruptions.

An impact of that magnitude will lead to extinction of most of the species, it should be bigger than any other extinction event in Earth's history. Still, many organisms, particularly primitive ones, will survive.

How soon after the impact the Earth will calm down? This is difficult to tell. Lava eruptions may last for hundreds of thousand years. Climate and atmosphere can be quite different during that time.

I am thinking, tough, that if future civilization is so advanced, why can't they do something to avoid asteroid impact?

Comment: I think to noticably rearrange continents, you'd need something on the order of Theia, the hypothesized giant impact body that split the primordial Earth into the Earth-Moon system:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_(planet)  In which case, you're looking at a billion years or so for repopulation, if the result is even habitable at all.

Comment: Wow. I did _think_ so too, but Theia is estimated to have been nearly Mars-sized. In the case of a planetary collision or even a planet-moon collision, I think the energy of the impact will absolutely melt all the crust, leaving behind no sign at all of the former continents. My estimate is a half-to-quarter moon sized asteroid. It is quite difficult to know objectively, as we never have had any direct view of a planetary scale collision anywhere. @jamesqf